# changing domain name for Mongodb primary

Tags: replication, mongodb

Im trying to initialize my replica set sp that the primary node has a specific domain:port pairing. what I want is:

> "vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:27022"

but what I get is:

> "localhost:27022"

This is the command I use to start the mongo instance:

> sudo mongod --port 27022 --dbpath /db/config/data --configsvr --replSet config

This is what I use to access the mongo instance:

> mongo --port 27022

I tried to modify my host file to add the domain name to the default domain of 127.0.0.1, but that didn't work.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

How do I get the specific "vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:27022" pairing when I initialize the mongo instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add replica set members with hostname, pass the host name when initializing the replica set.

```
rs.initiate(
    {
        _id: "config",
        version: 1,
        members: [
        {_id: 0, host: "vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:27022"}
        ]
    }
)
```

> _id --> is your replica set name

Or if you want to edit the existing configuration follow the below steps

```
var conf = rs.conf()

conf.members[0].host="vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:27022"

rs.reconfig(conf)
```

> If you have more than one member in your replica set, all members
>   should refer a hostname. Which means all members should be localhost or all members should be hostnames

Comment: it still gives me localhost:27022

Comment: Are you saying, you are localhost after connecting to the database in mongo shell?

Comment: once I initialize the mongodbi instance and access it, I do rs.initailize() and what I get is "me":"localhost:27022", but I want "me":"vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:27022"

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, x.x.x.x is the IP address of your VM.